# form get with value in mvc route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working with mvc4 and have a field where a user can enter some text in to an input field which gets passed to the url and redirect to another page eg. /search/<>

My form is as follows but redirects as query string.

```
<form class="search" action="@Url.Action("Index", "Search")">
<div>
    <input name="q" value="" type="search" />
    <input type="image" name="btn" value="search" src="@Url.Content("/image1.jpg")" />
</div>

</form>
```

Any idea how I could alter my form to pass the inputed value to input "q" to the url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `GET` method:

```
<form class="search" action="@Url.Action("Index", "Search")" method="get">
    <div>
        <input name="q" value="" type="search" />
        <input type="image" name="btn" value="search" src="@Url.Content("~/image1.jpg")" />
    </div>
</form>
```

You could also generate this exact same markup using the `Html.BeginForm` helper which is designed for this purpose:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "search" }))
{
    <div>
        <input name="q" value="" type="search" />
        <input type="image" name="btn" value="search" src="@Url.Content("~/image1.jpg")" />
    </div>
}
```

When you use the GET method all input element values will be sent in the query string when the form is submitted.

And if you want to append the search string in the path portion of the url instead of using a query string parameter I invite you to read the [`following blog post`](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) from Scott Hanselman. I will quote only his conclusion:

> After ALL this effort to get crazy stuff in the Request Path, it's
>   worth mentioning that simply keeping the values as a part of the Query
>   String (remember WAY back at the beginning of this post?) is easier,
>   cleaner, more flexible, and more secure.

Comment: Any idea how I could pass it to the url -> search/<<value>> Prefer not to have it in the query string.

Comment: This is something I wouldn't recommend you doing. You will encounter lots of problems with IIS not authorizing some special characters in the path portion of an url. Just read the following article to understand how hard it can be: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx If for some reason you decide to go against my advice you should be aware that there's nothing out of the box in HTML to support this. If you want to implement it you will have to write javascript code which harvests the value

Comment: from the input field and manually append it to whatever part of the query string you want it to appear. But even if you manage to write this javascript you will encounter much more serious problems with IIS later. Don't forget that the user is free to enter whatever characters he wants in this search field. I would very strongly advice you not doing that and simply use a normal query string parameter, just like most search engines already do. Just take a look at `bing.com` for example. You enter a value in the search field and this value appears as a `q` query string parameter when you submit.

Comment: ok, thanks for pointing this out. I am going to follow your approach

Comment: I have used both forms above but neither working. When I click the button - it redirects to ?q=Test&btn=search - not the action link. Any idea why?

Comment: When you click on the submit button it should redirect to `/Search/Index?q=Test&btn=search`.

Comment: I would prefer to exclude btn=search is this possible? Also, it does not redirect to search/index either bur stays on the same page.

Comment: Remove `name="btn"` from your submit button. If it stays on the same page it means that you served this view from the same controller action as the one you specified on your form.

Answer (score 0):

your Index view should look like

```
   @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }

    <h2>Index</h2>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home"))
    {
        @Html.TextBox("query")
    }
```

and your HomeController like

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public ActionResult Search(string query)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query) == false)
            return RedirectToAction(query);
        else 
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

1. Type name of the action where you want to be redirected in your textbox and then press enter
   Hope this helps :)

Comment: By query he meant that he wanted the value entered by the user to appear in the query string when the form is submitted.

Comment: Ok I am going to add RedirectToAction(query) in Search Action, does it  ok?

Comment: No, why would you be adding a redirect from your search controller action? The Search action is supposed to render the results of this query. Don't forget that at the end of the day you should display the results of the search. If you redirect, what's the point of this Search controller action? HTML already has a built-in way to achieve that. Look at my answer for the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Search(string query)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query) == false)
        return RedirectToAction("ACTION NAME",query);//prepend your action name
    else 
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: welcome to SO - please comment how your snippet can help with OP