# How To Prevent Query String but use routes in Html.BeginForm (GET)?

Tags: c#, search, model-view-controller, routes

I have a search page. I a search-panel I filled a model like this:

```
public class SearchVm
{
    public long? CategoryId { get; set; }
    public long? ProductId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FromDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ToDate { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And as we are interested in SEO,So I want use GET Method, to get search result. so my form is like this:

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Search", "Products", FormMethod.Get))
{...}
```

And here is action signature:

```
 public ActionResult Search(SearchVM esm){...}
```

But my URL is so ugly and if I don't fill property "IT IS" in URL as a query string:

http://localhost:8080/Products/Search?CategoryId=2&ProductId=&Text=&FromDate=&ToDate=

Here in this URL,I just filled "CategoryId"!
But how can I have a **dynamic route** for my searches like this:

```
"Products/Search/cat{CategoryId}/prod{ProductId}/{Text}/{FromDate}/{ToDate}"
"Products/Search/prod{ProductId}/{Text}/{FromDate}/{ToDate}"
"Products/Search/prod{ProductId}"
"Products/Search/cat{CategoryId}"
"Products/Search/{FromDate}/{ToDate}"
"Products/Search/{FromDate}"
```

Actually How Can I have all of these combination to be redirected to same action

Comment: can you show the signature for your action?

Comment: dear @CodingYoshi, I added Signature in my post

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14572008/4228458) answer and all the comments so you can see why querystring is better for user entered data. If you do not want the empty items in your querystring, you will need to write javascript for that since you will only know if they are empty just before the form is submitted. You will be able to find how to do that online if you search `remove empty querystring parameters with javascript`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you should use the query param for your search fields and not path param. But if you insist, use route attribute(System.Web.Mvc.Route) on your action like this:

```
Route("Products/Search/{FromDate}")
```

use all of the routes you would like to fire the related "ActionResult" method